# Accessing stateless components by ref (or key) in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some child functional components being rendered with via a map inside a parent component. The entire app renders a table, with the the stateless component in question rendering individual table cells.

I'm trying to gain access to all table cells in a specific column (to add a css class) by passing them a ref like so, except refs don't exist in stateless components:

```
const Cell = (props) => {
  return (
    <td className="cell" key={props.column}>
      ...
    </td>
  );
};
```

And I'm trying to avoid writing this as a class component. So far I've been using refs over `reactDOM.findDOMNode` for a few reasons and prefer to keep it that way. So my question is: Is there a more efficient method of gaining access to various DOM nodes without using refs or `reactDOM`? I've been trying to see if I can use the `key` property, but haven't made much progress there.

What makes this trickier is that I'm selecting cells in a column, and not just grabbing all the cells in any one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a prop to notify yourself your element was rendered, and therefore, mounted (**Not really mounted yet on first render, but will be mounted very soon, hope it is enough**).

Of course, since a stateless component only has the render method, if any prop changes, it will call again your function. You may need to control not to do extra logic for every renderization:

```
const Cell = (props) => {
  if (typeof props.onRender === 'function') {
    props.onRender(this);
  }
  return (
    <td className="cell" key={props.column}>
      ...
    </td>
  );
};
```

And the parent component:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  ...
  this.onRender = this.onRender.bind(this);
}

onRender(instance) {
  if (this.child !== undefined) {
    this.child = instance;
  }
}

render() {
  return <Cell {...desiredProps...} onRender={this.onRender} />
}
```

Comment: It's definitely an interesting concept, I hadn't thought of this... Although I get the feeling this is more heavy lifting than just turning the functional component into a class one.